# Infinite Coin Flips; Win-Loss Always Below 1/2

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Take the space of infinite coin flips where each outcome is either win (W) or loss (L) with a uniform measure.  I want to know the measure/probability of the sequences that have a win-loss rate always below 1/2

Example: (LLLLL...) belongs since its win-loss rate is always 0.  (LWLLLLLL...) does not belong as its win-loss rate at t=2 was exactly 1/2 (even though the sequences win-loss rate goes to 0 eventually)

I tried to write out how the sequence must start to see if there was a pattern.  For example it must start with L.  Let [L] be the set of sequences that start with L.  It has measure 1/2.  Continuing this way

Time 1: [L] measure 1/2,
Time 2: [LL] measure 1/4,
Time 3: [LLL], [LLW] measure 2/8,
Time 4: [LLLL], [LLLW], [LLWL] measure 3/6

Edited to explain the situation better

Comment: I don't get your question...each sequence of length $n$ has probability of $2^{-n}$ of happening at the beginning of your sequence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the win-loss rate is always below $1/2$ is actually $0$.  This is a standard question in probability; let $S_n$ be the number of wins minus the number of losses.  Then $S_n$ is a simple random walk, which is *recurrent*, meaning that $$P[S_n = 0 \text{ for infinitely many }n ] = 1\,.$$

There's a nice discussion about this on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk